# What signature algorithm does a key of type 'ec' use in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, cryptography

I believe a `KeyObject` having `asymmetricKeyType` of `ec` will use ECDSA to produce a signature, but I cannot find confirmation of this. Is ECDSA the signing algorithm used by an `ec` key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

Node.js doesn't seem to have the same API as e.g. .NET where algorithms and key objects are intermingled (thank goodness). So it is not as Object Oriented as it can be: instead of using `key.Sign`, you'd create a `Sign` object and use that. However, the key type may indeed play part in the selection of the actual signing algorithm.

It's not that easy to see indeed what algorithm is used if you just supply a hash as algorithm. However, there is a strong indication in the documentation of [`Sign.createSign`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptocreatesignalgorithm-options).

> In some cases, a `Sign` instance can be created using the name of a signature algorithm, such as `'RSA-SHA256'`, instead of a digest algorithm. This will use the corresponding digest algorithm. This does not work for all signature algorithms, **such as `'ecdsa-with-SHA256'`**, so it is best to always use digest algorithm names.

Which is of course completely ridiculous; in source code you would want to clearly specify the algorithm that you are using. Now for EC where ECDSA is almost ubiquitous it might make some sense. However, for RSA you can use PKCS#1 based padding or PSS based padding, and both are considered secure. And that's without diving into more esoteric algorithms such as the **deterministic** version of ECDSA.

To be honest, I consider this to be a bug in the crypto library of Node.js: you should always be able to specify the full algorithm & algorithm configuration explicitly. The key should then comply with the algorithm used, rather than to help define it.

Comment: tried to look this up in the documentation, I might test this in the future, but the chances of this not being ECDSA are about one in a million, so yeah...

Comment: This is probably due to a similar mistake in OpenSSL which nodejs wraps. When EAY started all signatures were 'prehash', and the OpenSSL `EVP_{Sign,Verify}*` APIs economized by sharing with `EVP_Digest*`; all 3 Init and Update routines are the same, and only Final differs: DigestFinal returns the digest, SignFinal uses it with privatekey (not supplied earlier) to sign, and VerifyFinal similarly uses it to verify. OpenSSL 1.0.0 in 2010 added better (but clumsily named) `EVP_Digest{Sign,Verify}*` which does get asymmetric key at Init, apparently too late for nodejs. ...

Comment: ... The 'oneshot' functions `crypto.sign` and `crypto.verify` added in nodejs v12 (separate from the `crypto.Sign` and `crypto.Verify` classes) _do_ use the better API and as a result can support PSS and EdDSA among other things.